# Write data in String.xml Android

Tags: android, programming-languages

I want to write some values from editText of activity in the file string.xml.
I will explain with an example:

In the activity I have 2 editText and 1 button to submit the information. Imagine that the editText are for inserting NAME and SURNAME.
I have the following code in string.xml

```
<string name="person_name"></string>
<string name="person_surname"></string>
```

At the begining, those fields will be empty but after submiting the info, I want to write the values obtained from the editTexts in that file.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although what you want is not possible but can be done through SharedPreferences http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Answer (score 6):

That's not possible. Strings.xml is only for storing predefined strings. Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store this data.