# Creating methods and updating strings

Tags: java, android

I am relatively new to Android development but I do have a pretty good understanding of Java and xml etc. so excuse me if this is an easy question and I just can't put two and two together.

Anyway, I am trying to have a user input a few characters into an EditText field. When they press a Button, it will call a method that will output a String. I then want this String to be displayed on the same activity as the EditText field and Button.

**How do I go about taking the String variable that is the result of the method and putting into a String in the strings.xml file?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233015/write-data-in-string-xml-android) question. I don't think that is possible, what you probably want to do is store what the user enters in SharedPreferences.

EDIT:
To take the string variable and display it on the screen you would want to add a TextView to your layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:text=""/>
```

Then in code you will add a listener to your button to listen for click events, and have a reference to the TextView in your class:

Fields in class:

```
TextView tv;
Button myButton;
EditText et;

onCreate():

tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);

//Now set the onclick listener:
myButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(args....) 
{
    String txt = et.getText().toString();
    tv.setText(txt);
}
});
```

Also check out [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-interface-design_basic-buttons/) tutorial.

Comment: Hmm, I see. I think I should rephrase my question though. What's the simplest way to just take the String variable and display it on the screen?

Comment: Ah, that's it right there. I want to kick myself for missing something so tiny. I had all the code in place with the exception of setText(variable); Thank you!