# Change String.xml file from Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Good morning friends,

Is it possible to modify the values of the string.xml folder?. I try to modify Spanish and English string.xml from java code, in the same way that I extract the information.

```
String text = getString(R.string.animal);
```

how to modify a `string.xml`?

Comment: been asked before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233015/write-data-in-string-xml-android

Comment: Simple answer: No

Comment: thanks for the reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, This is not possible in android at all.

Android does not support changing the resources dynamically from java, but it supports getting values from remote such as [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android).

Comment: thanks for the reply